# Plotly: stacked bars only in specific subplots

Tags: layout, plotly, subplot

I have two bar charts with two columns, created as follow:

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
trace1 = go.Bar(x=x1 , y=y1)
trace2 = go.Bar(x=x2, y=y2)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 1)
trace3 = go.Bar(x=x3 , y=y3)
trace4 = go.Bar(x=x4, y=y4)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(trace4, 1, 2)
```

I only want the second subplot with stacked bars. I tried the following

```
fig['layout']["xaxis2"].update(barmode='stack')
```

But this of course doesnt work. How do I apply the "stack" property to only the second subplot and not the whole figure?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you can use `offsetgroup = same` (same number in all graphs stacked).
and in the second bar `base=(first bar y)`

```py
    from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='dogs', x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6],
                         marker_color='blue',
                         marker=dict(color=[4, 5, 6], coloraxis="coloraxis")),
                  row=1, col=1)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='cats', x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3],
                         marker_color='yellow',
                         marker=dict(color=[4, 5, 6], coloraxis="coloraxis")),
                  row=1, col=1)
    female_y = [4,5,6]
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='female', x=[1, 2, 3], y=female_y,
                         offsetgroup=1, marker_color='green',
                         marker=dict(color=[4, 5, 6])),
                  row=1, col=2)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='male', x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 3, 5],
                         offsetgroup=1, marker_color='red',
                         base = female_y ,
                         marker=dict(color=[2, 3, 5])),
                  row=1, col=2)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='others', x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 1.2, 2.5],
                         offsetgroup=2, marker_color='rgb(0,255,255)',
                         marker=dict(color=[2, 3, 5])),
                  row=1, col=2)
    
    fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this forum answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-set-barmode-for-individual-subplots/47931/1) by a Plotly programmer, `barmode` is a figure-wide parameter and so this is not currently possible.